# Spring web this is MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is Spring web MVC architecture?
For example, we made a service that returns only JSON responses, can this be considered MVC architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC means Model View Controller, so if your model, view and controller is not tightly coupled you can call it MVC architecture. your response type have nothing to do with architecture, you can output json or xml or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON response is the View. It represents the data, but it is not necessary the complete data or data in the form that server stores them.

The Controller is the code that handles the request and works with the Model.

The Model is the internal way the data stored on the server side.